# How to store keys of a type argument in typescript without passing an instant?

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, type-safety

```
type TKeyed = { [key: string]: any };

class MyClass<T extends TKeyed> {
  private keysMap: Map<string, any>;

  constructor() {
    const keys = Object.keys({} as T); // Retrieve the keys of T
    this.keysMap = new Map<string, any>();

    for (const key of keys) {
      this.keysMap.set(key, null); // Store the keys in the Map
    }
  }

  getKeysMap(): Map<string, any> {
    return this.keysMap;
  }
}

interface MyType extends TKeyed {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: number;
}

const myInstance = new MyClass<MyType>();
const keysMap = myInstance.getKeysMap();

console.log(keysMap); // Output: Map { 'prop1' => null, 'prop2' => null }
```

This is what I'm trying to output:
`// Output: Map { 'prop1' => null, 'prop2' => null }`

But, the result is:
`Map (0) {}`

I've tried the above code using those methods to extract the keys:
`const keys = Reflect.ownKeys({} as T);`
It didn't work either.

Comment: `Object.keys({})` is an empty array no matter what.  Writing `as` in TypeScript doesn't change that; TypeScript has essentially no runtime effect. If you want keys of an object type, you need a *value* of that object type.

Comment: You can only go from concrete run-time artefact to a type-level artefact. Not the other way around. If you really need to examine the structure of something at run-time, then you need something concrete to work with. Perhaps you can construct the type out of it. With that said, that might also be [the wrong problem to solve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Focus on what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: With that said, you could probably writhe a plugin for TS that generates a concrete representation of a type to work with at run-time. That might be an overkill and likely would involve a lot more time and effort to create instead of another alternative. Again, depends on what your actual goal is here.